# React Native Access WebView Actions or WebView's ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I would like to be able to trigger some action a React Native App based on the Scroll events of a WebView e.g. Hide Elements when scrolled one way, return them when scrolled another way.

I have looked at the methods of WebView https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#content but cannot see anything exposed that would allow me to do this.

I could - as a really poor hack - inject some javascript and get it to set the title to a given value when scrolled and check for this value in the parent component but I'm hoping for a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're basically talking about this:

> It would be really great to be able to run JS inside of a WebView
>   component and register event listeners within regular React Native
>   code.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/586

Fortunately off the back of that, someone's started a project to bridge between the two:

> This is an attempt to create a Javascript Bridge between React Native
>   and Webview.

https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge

You have to use `WebViewBridge` instead of `WebView` but I wouldn't see that as a problem.

Comment: This would certainly be more elegant that my hacky way of doing it. I was hoping that there would be a way off accessing the scroll events directly but this should mean that I can detect and respond to scroll events. I've upvoted your answer and I'll update the question with the full answer once I've completed it for others. But will leave it unanswered in case there is a better solution then accept yours if not. Thank you.

Comment: If you do find a better solution then add it as an answer and accept it yourself, don't edit the question.